# Data Import from Excel Single Line creates Multi Line in SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, import

I haven't been able to find this question and was wondering if someone could please help.

I have imported a new list into SharePOint Foundation Server 2013 and some of the cells create a Multi Lined Field when they only require a Single Line Field.

I have done the advice of changing it to plain text and then to single line but then it brings up:
[image]

Can anyone assit on what I am missing?  I have made sure everything is text only and have even pasted to a new spreadsheet as values only.

Thanks in advance